# Bash single quotes inside double quotes

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, bash

I want to execute the command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat IPA -archivePath myApp.xcarchive -exportPath myApp.ipa -exportProvisioningProfile 'myApp adhoc'
```

The above command works fine when simply executing in terminal. However, I am attempting to execute the command inside a wrapper function in bash. The wrapper function works by being passed a command and then executing that command basically. For example, a call to the wrapperFunction:

```
wrapperFunction "xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat IPA -archivePath myApp.xcarchive -exportPath myApp.ipa -exportProvisioningProfile 'myApp adhoc'"
```

and the wrapperFunction itself:

```
wrapperFunction() {
    COMMAND="$1"
    $COMMAND
}
```

The problem is the single quotes in `'myApp adhoc'`, because when running the command through wrapperFunction I get the error: `error: no provisioning profile matches ''myApp'`. It is not picking up the full name of the provisioning profile `'myApp adhoc'`

**EDIT:** so say I also wanted to pass another string to wrapperFunction that was not part of the command to be executed. For example I wanted to pass a string to display if the command fails. Inside wrapperFunction I could check $? after the command and then display the failure string if $? -ne 0. How can I also pass a string with the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix code and data. Pass the arguments separately (this is what `sudo` and `find -exec` does):

```
wrapperFunction() {
    COMMAND=( "$@" )   # This follows your example, but could
    "${COMMAND[@]}"   # also be written as simply "$@" 
}

wrapperFunction xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat IPA -archivePath myApp.xcarchive -exportPath myApp.ipa -exportProvisioningProfile 'myApp adhoc'
```

To provide a custom error message:

```
wrapperFunction() { 
    error="$1" # get the first argument
    shift      # then remove it and move the others down
    if ! "$@"  # if command fails
    then 
      printf "%s: " "$error"  # write error message
      printf "%q " "$@"       # write command, copy-pastable
      printf "\n"             # line feed
    fi
}
wrapperFunction "Failed to frub the foo" frubber --foo="bar baz"
```

This produces the message `Failed to frub the foo: frubber --foo=bar\ baz`.

Since the method of quoting isn't important and isn't passed to commands or functions, the output may be quoted differently like here. They will still be functionally identical.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much. Care to elaborate on how it works a little more?

Comment: FWIW, the first example could be more simply written as `wrapperFunction() { "$@" ; }`. Presumably the reason to put the arguments into an array is to allow some sort of manipulation or inspection prior to the invocation of the wrapped function; that might be worth being made more explicit. Also, watch out for injected executables in such wrappers, especially if they run in insecure environments. `eval` is not the only security hole, although it is probably amongst the worst.

Comment: You pass in multiple arguments, and then execute the program with those arguments. This is opposed to trying to put multiple arguments into a string, interpretting them as shell code instead of arguments, hoping to get the arguments back out intact. If you're familiar with C, it's basically `int main(.., char* argv) { execve(argv[0], argv, ..); }` instead of `system(argv[1])`.

Comment: added more info to question. I also want to pass a string to wrapperFunction that is not part of command. How can I do that with this solution?

Comment: Thanks other guy. Awesome answer. Helped out a lot.